# SQL for Categorizing Based on Value in Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Probably very simple for some of you, but I'm boggled.  Thanks for any help!

I don't have any SQL that's close to working.

Here are the results I'm trying for:

I want to create Column D below based on the values in Column C, grouping by Column B and summing column A:

```
Column a||  Column b  ||Column c  ||Column d
$20         john        1           1&2
$30         john        2           1&2 
$20         sally       1           1
$20         suzie       2           2
$20         mary        3           3
$20         bob         1           1&2
$10         bob         2           1&2
$20         karen       1           1&3
$10         karen       3           1&3
```

Comment: This is for `Mysql` or `Sql Server` because both are very different

Comment: Yes, remove one of the db server tags so we know where to start.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether you want column `d` to contain a concatenation of column `c` or a sum of a column `a` values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two SQL-Server tags, I'm assuming SQL Server

```
Declare @YourTable table (colA int,colB varchar(50),colC int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(20,'john',1),
(30,'john',2),
(20,'sally',1),
(20,'suzie',2),
(20,'mary',3),
(20,'bob',1),
(10,'bob',2),
(20,'karen',1),
(10,'karen',3)

Select *
      ,ColD = Replace((Select String=Stuff((Select ',' +cast(colC as varchar(25)) From  @YourTable Where ColB=A.ColB For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') ) ,',','&')
 From @YourTable A
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use Common Table Expressions and `FOR XML`. The following sample query will group by B, combine column C and provide a sum of A.

```
WITH MyTable (A,B,C)
AS
(
    SELECT A,B,C
    FROM TestT
)

SELECT t1.B, SUM(a) AS SumOfA,
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(C AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM MyTable t2
        WHERE t1.B = t2.B
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS D

FROM MyTable t1

GROUP BY t1.B
```

This will produce the following:

```
B       SumOfA  D
bob     30      1, 2
john    50      1, 2
karen   30      1, 3
mary    20      3
sally   20      1
suzie   20      2
```